# How do I pass a Perl array to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, perl

I want to pass an array created dynamically in Perl to a JavaScript function. I do not want to pass it element by element. How do
I process it in the JavaScript function?

```
my @perlArray;
<input type='button' onClick=call_me(perlArray) >
```

JavaScript:

```
function call_me(PassedArray){

#process the array

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JSON::XS`](http://p3rl.org/JSON%3a%3aXS) to serialize array and just print resulting string between brackets of JS function call, escaping it for HTML with any suitable module (like `HTML::Entities`).

Comment: Don't use `JSON::XS`, use [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) - it will use `JSON::XS` or `JSON::PP` depending on what is available.

Comment: It also won't make the data safe for inserting into an HTML document.

Comment: @Quentin, concern about escaping is valid and I'll edit it in, but speaking about flavors of `JSON` module, I'd rather explicitly include ::XS to get speed and guaranteed ::XS API, rather than play backend detection game.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: the rule of optimization is not to do it unless you find your program runs too slowly. `use JSON` will get you the fastest implementation of JSON that is installed. Insisting on the XS version is probably pointless and may prevent the program from running when it would be fine under a pure Perl implementation